# Why is Visual Studio erasing my files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

It happened many many times, and still does.
I close Visual Studio, I turn off my computer, I go there again the next day, and guess what, every code files were erased.
If it wasn't for backups, I couldn't retrieve anything back.
Why does it do that?
I don't always backup. For instance, I didn't backup the last 4 days, and it erased the code file I was mostly working with. 4 days of work, gone. I can retrieve some stuff only because of backups. Otherwise, I would have lost months of work.

This is getting really frustrating and frequent.
What can I do?

By the way, it never happened in the old versions of visual studio, only on the 2013 version.~

Also, Visual Studio erased the backups aswell, or at least they are there.

Comment: And what exactly makes you think Visual Studio is guilty of erasing your files instead of, say, a random rogue program on your machine?

Comment: First off, use some sort of *source control*, and don't rely on backups.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi because it's after I close Visual Studio. VS is the last I close and I always save it before. But it still erases it. And, I don't have any program on my machine that tickles with VS projects.

Comment: Why are so many people disliking this question??

Comment: Probably because we have a hard time believing Visual Studio is nuking your files (not to speak of your *backups*), and you do not provide enough information for us to identify a potential culprit.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It really is. There are no other programs left open after I save and close Visual Studio. I don't have any more info.

Comment: @user, I believe the most important information you can provide is the location where these files reside. You can also do the following: close VS and shutdown Windows as usual, then boot a Linux LiveCD/USB, mount your hard drive and look for your files. Are they still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this just one project? If you create a new project what happens? Did you convert this project from VS1010? There are major changes in VS2012 which can easily break old projects, depending on how they were built. Broken projects can behave very strangely.

I can't give you an exact reason why, other than the above. The solution is to create a brand new project and just copy the source code files across.

If the problem exists on a new test project, or reoccurs on a new project you create then it's a gremlin hunt. Or as Sir Fred Hoyle famously wrote in "The Black Cloud": “Because bastard inside, maybe”.

And get  yourself on source control (Subversion is the easiest).

Comment: I thinks it's on all projects. But I am not sure. I started this project right after updating VS. It's a 2013 project, no conversion.